# Which call faster href vs onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, href

Hi~ i want to calling sequence about anchor tag href property and onclick proerty I have some test 
`<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" onclick="alert('asdf');">asdfasdf</a>`

and click anchor tag. is result show alert and link stackoverflow but

`<a onclick="setTimeout(function(){console.log('asdf')})" href="https://stackoverflow.com" >test</a>`
this tag first call href proerty! Please explain calling
sequence href and onclick
and if you know another knowledge explain for me Please ToT

Comment: @Sinto, that's actually not true. Please don't use comments to say 'I think'. They are for clarification or to point out problems. If you have a solution, make an actual solution and provide evidence that you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So onclick functions actually run before href. This allows you to do a number of really cool things, like stop the link from executing if you want to like so:

```js
function stopLink(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank" onclick="stopLink">click me</a>
```

Comment: So to be clear, I used preventDefault() as an example to visually show that the js runs before the link gets executed. If you had prompted the user for input it would also work to show a visual difference. Otherwise, js runs fast enough that you wouldn't really see any delay in the link getting executed. However, the fact that the preventDefault function works at all shows that it is being executed before the link